# ¿Es posible bloquear un input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo dos botones. Uno agregar archivo y otro Remover:

```
<label>Elegir imagen de vista previa:</label><br />

<input type="button" value="Eliminar Archivo" id="clear1" class="clear" style="color:black; float: left;">
<input type="file" name="UploadFile1" id="control1" class="UploadFile1" style="float: left;">
```

¿Es posible ponerle limite de solo un archivo? 
Es decir, que al subir un archivo, el botón subir archivo se bloquee a menos que haga clic en el botón *remove*. Sin desaparecer ni nada, algo así como desactivarlo pero manteniendo la estética.

Comment: sí se puede hay un atributo `disabled` para ello puedes mirar los docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled

Comment: Si como ya te comentan con el atributo `disabled` de esta forma: `<input disabled type="text">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indico a continuación posible solución:

1. En el botón de tipo "file", cuando se cargue valor de fichero, desactivar con `onchange="this.disabled=true;"`
2. Cuando se pulse el botón "Eliminar Archivo", dejar el nombre de fichero en blanco y activar de nuevo el botón "file" con `onclick="obj=document.getElementById('control1');obj.value='';obj.disabled=false"`

```html
    <input type="button" value="Eliminar Archivo" 
      onclick="obj=document.getElementById('control1');obj.value='';obj.disabled=false">
    <input type="file" name="UploadFile1" id="control1" onchange="this.disabled=true;">
```

Saludos.